# App startup failure due to missing `basic_streambuf` symbol in `libgnustl_shared.so` library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Full name is

```
_ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekposESt4fposI9mbstate_tESt13_Ios_Openmode
```

and it is a weak symbol in `libgnustl_shared.so` library that resides in Android NDK 10.5.0, e.g., for gcc 4.9 for armeabi-v7a, in directory

```
sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/
```

. I get a start up error on the device:

> W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen
>   failed: cannot locate symbol ...

even though the library seems to contains weak default definition for it...

Comment: Do you see the same issue in a newer NDK? r10e is quite old.

Comment: I haven't tried it with the newer NDK, no. I can't upgrade NDK.

Comment: There probably ins't a fix for you then. This doesn't look like user error, it looks like a bug, and fixing that would require being able to update to a version with the fix. It's possible that gnustl_static works.